# javac cannot compile upper bounded wildcard but Eclipse can

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, javac

I am working with a code base that has relied on Eclipse for compilation until now. My objective is to compile it with `javac` (via `ant`) to simplify the build process. The project compiles without complaint in Eclipse (version 2019-12 (4.14.0)), but `javac` (OpenJDK, both versions 1.8.0_275 and 14.0.2) produces `method ... cannot be applied to given types` errors involving upper bounded wildcards.

### Steps to reproduce

Note that the repository is 64 MB at time of writing:

```sh
git clone git@github.com:jamesdamillington/CRAFTY_Brazil.git
cd CRAFTY_Brazil && git checkout 550e88e
javac -Xdiags:verbose \
    -classpath bin:lib/jts-1.13.jar:lib/MORe.jar:lib/ParMa.jar:lib/ModellingUtilities.jar:lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:lib/repast.simphony.bin_and_src.jar \
    src/org/volante/abm/agent/DefaultSocialLandUseAgent.java
```

Error message output:

```
src/org/volante/abm/agent/DefaultSocialLandUseAgent.java:166: error: method removeNode in interface MoreNetworkModifier<AgentType,EdgeType> cannot be applied to given types;
                        this.region.getNetworkService().removeNode(this.region.getNetwork(), this);
                                                       ^
  required: MoreNetwork<SocialAgent,CAP#1>,SocialAgent
  found: MoreNetwork<SocialAgent,MoreEdge<SocialAgent>>,DefaultSocialLandUseAgent
  reason: argument mismatch; MoreNetwork<SocialAgent,MoreEdge<SocialAgent>> cannot be converted to MoreNetwork<SocialAgent,CAP#1>
  where AgentType,EdgeType are type-variables:
    AgentType extends Object declared in interface MoreNetworkModifier
    EdgeType extends MoreEdge<? super AgentType> declared in interface MoreNetworkModifier
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends MoreEdge<SocialAgent> from capture of ? extends MoreEdge<SocialAgent>
1 error
```

For completeness the method containing the offending line is:

```java
public void die() {
    if (this.region.getNetworkService() != null && this.region.getNetwork() != null) {
        this.region.getNetworkService().removeNode(this.region.getNetwork(), this);
    }

    if (this.region.getGeography() != null
            && this.region.getGeography().getGeometry(this) != null) {
        this.region.getGeography().move(this, null);
    }
}
```

### Analysis of error message

1. We're told the compiler found type `MoreNetwork<SocialAgent,MoreEdge<SocialAgent>>` where it required `MoreNetwork<SocialAgent,CAP#1>`.
2. This implies the inferred value of `CAP#1` is incompatible with `MoreEdge<SocialAgent>`
3. However we're told `CAP#1 extends MoreEdge<SocialAgent> from capture of ? extends MoreEdge<SocialAgent>`

The [Java documentation on Upper Bounded Wildcards](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html) states that

> The upper bounded wildcard, `<? extends Foo>`, where `Foo` is any type, matches `Foo` and any subtype of `Foo`.

I cannot see why `MoreEdge<SocialAgent>` doesn't match `<? extends MoreEdge<SocialAgent>>`, and consequently cannot reconcile 2 and 3.

### Efforts made to resolve the problem

While my objective is to compile for Java 8, I am aware that there have been bugs found in `javac` related to generics and wildcards in the past (see [discussion around this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38246476)). However, I find the same problem with both javac 1.8.0_275 and javac 14.0.2.

I also thought about whether some form of explicit cast might provide the compiler with sufficient hints. However I can't think what to change since the type of `this.region.getNetwork()` is reported as `MoreNetwork<SocialAgent,MoreEdge<SocialAgent>>` in the error message as expected.

### Generalisation of the problem (EDIT)

@rzwitserloot rightly pointed out that I hadn't included enough information about the dependencies in the code above to properly debug. Copying all the dependencies (including some code from libraries I don't control) would get very messy so I have distilled the problem into a self-contained program that produces an analogous error.

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class UpperBoundNestedGenericsDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MapContainerManagerBroken mapContainerManager = new MapContainerManagerBroken();
        MapContainer<A, B<A>> mapContainer = new MapContainer<>();
        mapContainerManager.setMapContainer(mapContainer);

        Map<A, B<A>> aMap = new HashMap<>();
        aMap.put(new A(), new B<A>());
        
        mapContainerManager.getMapContainer().addMap(aMap);
        mapContainerManager.getMapContainer().removeMap(aMap);
    }

}

/**
 * Analogue of Region
 */
class MapContainerManagerBroken {
    private MapContainer<A, ? extends B<A>> mapContainer;

    void setMapContainer(MapContainer<A, ? extends B<A>> mapContainer) {
        this.mapContainer = mapContainer;
    }

    MapContainer<A, ? extends B<A>> getMapContainer() {
        return this.mapContainer;
    }
}

/**
 * Analogue of MoreNetworkService
 */
class MapContainer<T1, T2> {

    List<Map<T1, T2>> listOfMaps = new ArrayList<>();

    void addMap(Map<T1, T2> map) {
        listOfMaps.add(map);
    }

    boolean removeMap(Map<T1, T2> map) {
        return listOfMaps.remove(map);
    }

}

class A {
}

class B<T> {
}
```

This compiles in Eclipse, but upon compiling with

```sh
javac -Xdiags:verbose UpperBoundNestedGenericsDemo.java
```

produces the error message

```
UpperBoundNestedGenericsDemo.java:18: error: method addMap in class MapContainer<T1,T2> cannot be applied to given types;
                mapContainerManager.getMapContainer().addMap(aMap);
                                                     ^
  required: Map<A,CAP#1>
  found: Map<A,B<A>>
  reason: argument mismatch; Map<A,B<A>> cannot be converted to Map<A,CAP#1>
  where T1,T2 are type-variables:
    T1 extends Object declared in class MapContainer
    T2 extends Object declared in class MapContainer
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends B<A> from capture of ? extends B<A>
UpperBoundNestedGenericsDemo.java:19: error: method removeMap in class MapContainer<T1,T2> cannot be applied to given types;
                mapContainerManager.getMapContainer().removeMap(aMap);
                                                     ^
  required: Map<A,CAP#1>
  found: Map<A,B<A>>
  reason: argument mismatch; Map<A,B<A>> cannot be converted to Map<A,CAP#1>
  where T1,T2 are type-variables:
    T1 extends Object declared in class MapContainer
    T2 extends Object declared in class MapContainer
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends B<A> from capture of ? extends B<A>
2 errors
```

### Partial solution

The program in the previous section can be modified such that it compiles under both Eclipse and `javac` by replacing `MapContainerManagerBroken` with

```java
class MapContainerManagerNoWildcards {
    private MapContainer<A, B<A>> mapContainer;
    
    void setMapContainer(MapContainer<A, B<A>> mapContainer) {
        this.mapContainer = mapContainer;
    }
    
    MapContainer<A, B<A>> getMapContainer() {
        return this.mapContainer;
    }
}
```

That is, by removing the wildcard type bounds for `MapContainer`. This solves the immediate practical problem, but limits the flexibility of `MapContainerManagerNoWildcards` compared to `MapContainerManagerBroken`. An alternative would be to make this class generic, e.g.

```java
class MapContainerManagerFixedGeneric<T extends B<A>> {
    private MapContainer<A, T> mapContainer;

    void setMapContainer(MapContainer<A, T> mapContainer) {
        this.mapContainer = mapContainer;
    }

    MapContainer<A, T> getMapContainer() {
        return this.mapContainer;
    }
}
```

However, this does not explain why the line `mapContainerManager.getMapContainer().addMap(aMap)` is a compiler error when `mapContainerManager` is a `MapContainerManagerBroken` (such as in the example program). Specifically, why is the preceding line an error, but the following compiles?

```java
MapContainer<A, ? extends B<A>> mapContainer = new MapContainer<A, B<A>>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misunderstood the rules on what `? extends` means as far as type compatibility is concerned.

Any two occurrences of `? extends Number` are not compatible with each other, nor is `? extends Number` compatible with `Number` itself. Here is a trivial 'proof' of why that is:

```
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<? extends Number> numbers1 = ints; // legal
List<Number> numbers2 = numbers1; // legal?
numbers2.add(new Double(5.0)); // oh whoopsie
```

If the above compiles, then there is a non-int in `ints`, and that's no good. Fortunately, it doesn't compile. Specifically, the third line is a compiler error.

The segment of the JLS you are talking about is talking about a one-way street. You can assign a `List<Number>` to a variable of type `List<? extends Number>` (or pass a `List<Number>` as argument when the argument is of that type), but not the other way around.

`?` is the same as 'imagine I used a letter here and that I use this letter only here and nowhere else'. Thus, if you have two `?` involved, they may not be equal to each other. Therefore, for type compatibility purposes, they aren't compatible. This makes sense; imagine you have:

```
void foo(List<? extends Number> a, List<? extends Number b>) {}
```

then it stands to reason that the point is that I can invoke this passing some `List<Integer>` for a and `List<Double>` for b: Each `?` gets to be whatever it wants as long as it fits the bounds. Which also means that it is **impossible** to invoke `add` on either of these lists, as the thing you add must be of type `?`, and you can't make that happen (except, trivially, by writing `.add(null)`, as null is every type for such purposes), but that's not very useful). It also explains why you can't write `a = b;` and that goes to the heart of your problem here. Why can you not assign `a` to `b`? They are the same type, after all! - No, they are not, and that CAP stuff captures this: a is of type `CAP#1` and b is of type `CAP#2`. That's how javac (and ecj, presumably) sort this out, and that's why this CAP stuff is showing up. It's not a matter of the compiler being intentionally dense or underspecced. It's inherent in the complexities of generics.

Thus, yes: `CAP#1` is not the same as `? extends Number`, it is merely one capture of that (and any further `? extends Number` would then be referred to as `CAP#2`, and CAP#1 and CAP#2 are not compatible; one may be Integer and one may be Double, after all). The error message itself **is sensible**.

Normally if `ecj` and `javac` disagree, usually `ecj` is correct and javac is not, based on personal experience (I recount about 10 times I ran into a situation where ecj and javac disagreed, and 9 out of the 10 times, ecj was more correct than javac; though often it is an ambiguity in the JLS that I then report and which have been resolved). Nevertheless, given that JDK14 still has the issue, and trying to interpret these error messages (this is quite difficult without all the signatures involved here, you haven't pasted the useful parts of your codebase), it does look like `javac` is correct.

The usual fix is to toss more `?` in there. In particular, a `removeEdge` sure sounds like it should accept either `Object` or `? extends T` and not `T`. After all, arraylist's `.remove()` method accepts any object, not a `T` - trying to remove some double from a list of ints simply doesn't do anything, as per spec: Asking a list to remove a thing that isn't inside is a noop. No reason to limit the parameter, then. That solves many problems right there.

---

EDIT, after you've significantly updated your question with way more detail.

> MapContainer<A, ? extends B> mapContainer = new MapContainer<A, B>();

Because that's what that means. Remember, `MapContainer<? extends Number>` does not represent a type. It represents a whole dimension worth of types. It's saying that `mapContainer` is a reference that can point at almost anything, as long as it is a MapContainer, of any 'tag' (the stuff in the `<>` you please, long as the thing that is in between is either Number or any subtype thereof. The only methods you can invoke on this exploded 'could be so many things' type is what *ALL* possible things it could be have in command, and **no `addMap` method of any stripe is a part of the intersection**. The `addMap` method's parameter involves an `A`, as in, in this example, the same thing as `? extends Number` and the compiler says: Well, I don't know. There is no type that fits. I can't go with `Number`; what if you have a `MapContainer<Integer>`? If I let you call `addMap` using any `Number`, you could put a Double in there, and that's not allowed. The fact that eclipse allows it at all is bizarre.

Here is a borderline trivial example:

```
Map<? extends Number, String> x = ...;
x.put(A, B);
```

In the above example, **nothing** can be written on either the 3 dots, or in place of `A` to make that **ever compile**. `? extends` is shorthand for: No add/put. Period.

There is actually one thing that will work: `x.put(null, B);`, because null 'fits' every type. But this is a copout and not at all useful for serious code.

Once you fully grok this, the problem is explained. More generally, given that you have a `MapContainer<? extends something>`, **you can't call addMap on that thing**. Period. You can't call 'write' operations on `extends` style typebounds.

I've explained why that is at the very top of this answer.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed response. I didn't paste `removeNode`'s source because it is part of a library and therefore not part of my codebase, and something I considered fixed. While I follow your nice and intuitive code proof, the broader concepts here will take some time to sink in. I'll have a go at implementing an adapter that accounts for your guidance regarding `removeEdge`'s signature above, and hopefully have this answer accepted by the end of the day.

Comment: I've modified the question to include a self-contained program that reproduces the problem and a partial solution. I've marked your answer accepted as I believe the problem is to do with multiple instances of `? extends X` not being equivalent.

Comment: @AndrewL answer edited to take into account the new information.

Comment: Okay, "You can't call 'write' operations on `extends` style typebounds."  has made the penny drop, thank you. This is documented in [Guidelines for Wildcard Use](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcardGuidelines.html), according to whose terminology the argument to `addMap` is an "in variable". What got me was that `MapContainer` does not involve wildcard bounds, though I see that mutating a `MapContainer` instance would cause problems for its containing `MapContainerManagerBroken` due to wildcards in the latter.